# Receiving "NO CARRIER" error while tring to execute AT cmd "AT$QCRMCALL=1,1"

Tags: linux, gsm, at-command, imx8

I am using linux 20.04 to build an image for the IMX8QXP, the image is based on kernel SUMO 4.14.98.
I am using one of the SIMCOM7600E.

I starts to dial up via NIC by using below command :

AT+CREG = 1
+CREG=1,1
return OK

AT+CGREG = 1
+CGREG=1,1
return OK

AT$QCRMCALL=1,1
return No CARRIER

I cant seem to fix the problem or figure out what is wrong. Please help me trouble shoot the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be:

1. The module can be registered in network, but the selected network mode may be unsuitable for data transmission (e.g. voice calls only or other). Check the preferred mode by using `AT+CNMP?`. The return value of 2 indicates auto.
2. Make sure that you have data plan available. Also remove PIN lock on the SIM card
3. Check if the signal quality is decent: try `AT+CSQ`. Its return value will be in format ,. RSSI stands for Received Signal Strength Indicator and BER for Bit Error Rate. RSSI value ranges can be in between 0 (minimum, =< -113dBm) to 31 (maximum, >= -51 dBm).
4. Look for more information about the operator: `AT+COPS?` and the network mode: `AT+CPSI?`
5. Based on the information obtained in previous steps, use an appropriate antenna or adjust its location if necessary
6. Don't forget about the stable power supply
7. If you didn't have much success with `AT$QCRMCALL=1,1`, try changing the USB PID of the module to 9011 (for using the modules as a RNDIS modem): `AT+CUSBPIDSWITCH=9011,1,1` (the default PID is 9001)
8. I would flash a new firmware only as a last resort. Usually this is not necessary

Reference:

1. [SIM7600 AT Commands manual v3.0](https://www.waveshare.net/w/upload/a/af/SIM7500_SIM7600_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V3.00.pdf)

Comment: hi, i was trying to fix the AT$QCRMCALL=1,1 return No CARRIER issue with the SIM8200EA-M2 5G HAT. Following your suggestion i get: 
1. AT+CNMP?. The return value of 2. 
3. AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 26,99

4. AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"vodafone IT",7
AT+CPSI?
+CPSI: LTE,Online,222-10,0x2F17,4994356,240,EUTRAN-BAND7,3025,4,4,-146,-924,-596,-2

6. Power supply is stable. 
7. Furthermore the USB port by def was already 9011. Trying to execute the AT+CUSBPIDSWITCH=9001,1,1 gives me an error. Do u have any other suggestions?

Comment: @LiudmilaDobriakova hello) the sad part is that AT$QCRMCALL=1,1 will return NO CARRIER if the connection is already established. In your case the module seems to be working okay. Check APN settings (see AT+CGDCONT command in the manual of SIM8200). Also, USB pid switching commands are likely to be different for SIM8200 than SIM7600, so please check the manual for your HAT module.

Comment: AT+CGDCONT?
+CGDCONT: 1,"IP","mobile.vodafone.it","0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,"",,,,0
+CGDCONT: 2,"IPV4V6","mobile.vodafone.it","0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,"",,,,0
+CGDCONT: 3,"IPV4V6","IMS","0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,"",,,,0
+CGDCONT: 38,"IPV6","v2x_ip","0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,"",,,,0
+CGDCONT: 39,"IPV6","v2x_non_ip","0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0",0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,"",,,,0
+CGDCONT: 4,"IPV4V6","sos","0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0",0,0,0,1,,,,,,,,,"",,,,0

OK

Comment: if the module is working ok why i can't connect to internet then? how can i enable the internet connection on Windows?

Comment: try switching it to 9001 mode by issuing at+cusbcfg=usbid,1e0e,9001 then install drivers for windows.

Comment: since you have a different module (not SIM7600), I think creating a new SO question might be more helpful for you

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks like it make it works.. U save my day!